# Cached entities making round trip to database

Tags: vb.net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

i am caching objects, if i make linq queries on cached entities then... will theses queries make database round trip due to lazy loading in Entity framework?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but they probably *will* if you access a property that is lazily loaded, but shouldn't for properties that were fetched the first-time around. I believe this only applies if said properties are marked `virtual`. You will not get lazy properties if you don't mark them as `virtual`.

Comment: you are right ...first time it fetch what about navigation properties i think are lazy loaded right... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not detach the entities before you caching them the entities will keep a reference to the context that created them and use it to lazy load. It is better to detach the entities.

```
context.Detach(entity);
cachedItems.Add(entity);
```